# Unhandled Exception: type '(T) => String' is not a subtype of type '(Object) => String'

Tags: generics, dart

I have an unexpected error. Here is the simplified code that produces the error in the title:

```
typedef ItemView<T> = String Function(T);

class Item {
  final String title;

  Item(this.title);
}

class Field<T, A> {
  final T value;
  final A attributes;

  Field(this.attributes, this.value);
}

class Attributes<T> {
  final List<T> items;
  final ItemView<T> itemToString;

  Attributes(this.items, this.itemToString);
}

void main() {
  final fields = [createField<Item>(
      [Item("Value 1"), Item("Value 2")], (item) => item.title)];

  if (fields[0] is Field<Object, Attributes<Object>>) {
    final field = fields[0] as Field<Object, Attributes<Object>>;
    final a = field.attributes;

    String text = a.itemToString(a.items[0]); // Unhandled Exception: type '(Item) => String' is not a subtype of type '(Object) => String'
    print(text); 
  }
}

Field<Object, Object> createField<T>(List<T> items, ItemView<T> itemToString) {
  final attributes = Attributes<T>(items, itemToString);
  final field = Field<T, Attributes<T>>(attributes, null);
  return field;
}
```

This code throws an error, but I was expecting a "Value 1" message.
Struggling with the code some time I've figured out the if I change the code a bit like that:

```
class Attributes<T> {
  final List<T> items;
  final ItemView<T> _itemToString;

  Attributes(this.items, this._itemToString);

  String itemToString(T value) {
    return _itemToString(value);
  }
}
```

It will work as I expect. So the question is: why the first variant doesn't work? Is it an expected behavior? Or it some kind of a bug? And what is the significant difference btw the first and the second code, so that it makes code valid?

Comment: I think this is one of the cases where `dart`'s `type inference` is getting confused.

Comment: Yea, I think something like that either.